# For $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, the function $f: A \to \mathbb R$, $f(x)=x^2$ is a uniform continuous function if?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

For $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, the function $f: A \to \mathbb R$, $f(x)=x^2$ is a uniform continuous function if

(A) A is bounded

(B) A is unbounded

(C) A is compact

(D) A is the set $\mathbb Z$ of all integers.

> My attempt:

(A) If $A$ is a bounded set then from the mean value theorem, we will have that $|f(x)-f(y)|\le M|x-y|$. Hence, $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous.

(C) If $A$ is compact, then $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous.

For options (B) and (D), using definition of uniform continuity,
$$|x^2-y^2|\le |x-y||x+y|$$ But if $A$ is unbounded of $\mathbb Z$, then there's no bound for $|x+y|$, so in my opinion only (A) and (C) are the correct options.

I don't know how to check for options (B) and (D).

> The answer is: (A), (B), (C), (D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (D), the subspace topology on $\mathbb Z$ is discrete.  So $\delta = \frac{1}{2}$ will ensure that $$|x-y| < \delta \implies x=y \implies |f(x) - f(y)| = 0 < \epsilon$$

I think (B) is inconclusive.  In light of (D), $f$ could be uniformly continuous on an unbounded set.  But $f$ is definitely not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$, another unbounded set.

I started to prove that $f$ couldn't be uniformly continuous on $A$ if $A$ was unbounded.  Here is how that proof went: we want to show that there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $\delta > 0$ there exists $x$ and $y$ in $A$ with $|x - y | < \delta$ but $|f(x) - f(y) | \geq \epsilon$.  Let $\epsilon = 1$.  Given $\delta > 0$, there exists $x \in A$ such that $|x| > \frac{1}{\delta}$.  Notice that for all $y$,
$$
    |f(x) - f(y)| = |f'(c)||x-y| = 2|c| |x-y|
$$
for some $c$ between $x$ and $y$.  If there exists $y \in A$ such that $|y| > |x|$ and $\frac{\delta}{2} < |x-y| < \delta $, we are done, because
$$
    2|c| |x-y| > 2 |x| |x-y| > 2 \cdot \frac{1}{\delta} \cdot \frac{\delta}{2} =1
$$
Since $A$ is unbounded, there definitely exists $y \in A$ with $|y| > |x|$. But the second condition isn't guaranteed, and fails for discrete sets like $\mathbb Z$.

Like @zhw says in the comments, since it's not true that $f$ is uniformly continuous on every unbounded set $A$, the statement “If $A$ is unbounded, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $A$” is false.  But in light of (D), the statement, “If $A$ is unbounded, then $f$ is *not* uniformly continuous on $A$” is also false.

Comment: Oh, so it depends on the unbounded set, but since $A \subset \mathbb{R}$,$A \neq \mathbb{R}$ would that be of any help? @MatthewLeingang

Comment: (B) is simply false.